# Openapi-Generator creates wrong typescript having polymorphism

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle, openapi-generator

I have the following DTOs:

```cs
public class InvoiceCreate{
    pubilc IEnumerable<ProductCreate> Products{get;set;}
}

public abstract class ProductCreate{
    public int number{get;set}
    public decimal price{get; set;}
}

public class TestProductCreate : ProductCreate{ }

public class SecondProductCreate: ProductCreate{ }
```

In my swashbuckle-configuration I have the following configuration:

```cs
c.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
c.UseAllOfForInheritance();
c.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();
c.SelectDiscriminatorNameUsing(type => "Type");
c.SelectSubTypesUsing(baseType =>
{
    return typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(baseType));
});
```

From my point of view, the generated swagger.json looks good:

```json
   "InvoiceCreate": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "products": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "oneOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TestProductCreate"
                },
                {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SecondProductCreate"
                }
              ],
              "description": ""
            },
            "description": "",
            "nullable": true
          },
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "description": ""
      },
 "ProductCreate": {
    "required": [
        "number",
        "price",
        "Type"
    ],
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Type": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "number": {
            "type": "number",
            "description": ""
        },
        "price": {
            "type": "number",
            "description": "",
            "format": "double"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "description": "",
    "discriminator": {
        "propertyName": "Type"
    }
},
 "TestProductCreate": {
    "type": "object",
    "allOf": [
        {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ProductCreate"
        }
    ],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "description": ""
},
"SecondProductCreate": {
    "type": "object",
    "allOf": [
        {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ProductCreate"
        }
    ],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "description": ""
},
```

But when I run the openapi-generator it creates an Invoice-Model with the following imports:

```js
import type { TestProductCreate  | SecondProductCreate  } from './TestProductCreate | SecondProductCreate';
import {
    TestProductCreate | SecondProductCreateFromJSON,
    TestProductCreate | SecondProductCreateJSONTyped,
    TestProductCreate | SecondProductCreateToJSON,
} from './TestProductCreate | SecondProductCreate;
```

Is this an bug in openapi-generator?

Having all Subtypes in dedicated lists (in invoice) the generated code looks well:

```cs
public class InvoiceCreate{
    pubilc IEnumerable<TestProductCreate > TestProducts{get;set;}
    pubilc IEnumerable<SecondProductCreate> SecondProducts{get;set;}
}
```

is there any clever trick so that I can have the single "Product" list with its inheritances?